# Derivation of the equations for non-uniform circular motion using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-numbers, physics

Here http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node89.html

They use complex analysis to derive the equations of non-uniform circular motion.

My confusion is this: In the derivation they basically say that unit-vector r is equal to e^(itheta) and unit-vector theta is equal to ie^(itheta). While I do understand that they have a very similar geometrical meaning, I don't know how you can say "they're equal". It just doesn't make sense forme me that you can set up an equality here.

How is that they're equal?

I'm starting to think that perhaps they're not equal (because they never explicitly say so) but it's just a very useful analogy, or something like that.

Thanks a lot, and I hope my question is not unclear. BTW, complex numbers are new for me so I'd appreciate if you don't use really advanced jargon. Thanks again.

Comment: The radial unit vector is nothing more than your vector normalized, so $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ which is equivalent to $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Your $\theta$ unit vector is a unit vector perpendicular to this, which leaves you only two choices: $i$ times your radial unit vector or $-i$ times your radial unit vector. The reason it has to be $\pm i$ times your radial unit vector is that you need a vector that is $90^{\circ}$ out of phase with your radial unit vector (so that they are perpendicular).

Comment: Two unit length complex numbers are perpendicular if and only if they are multiples of $\pm i$ of each other. The reason being that to rotate a complex number by $\pm 90^{\circ}$, you need to multiply by $e^{\pm i\pi/2} = \pm i$. You choose $i$ because you want your theta unit vector to point in the direction of rotation.

Comment: "nothing more than your vector normalized" do you mean the position vector given in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: But the radial unit vector is a vector and cosθ+isinθ is a number , I dont see how you can set up an equality. Why is this?

Comment: Your question is a bit more about the relationship between complex numbers and $\Bbb R^2$, then. Every vector in $\Bbb R^2$ has two components as you are undoubtedly well-aware. Graphically, we represent $\Bbb R^2$ as a plane. The complex numbers are numbers of the form $x+iy$, meaning complex numbers have two variables: $x$ and $y$. So complex numbers are like a two-dimensional real vector space. Graphically, we represent complex numbers as a plane with the horizontal axis being our real axis (like our component $(1,0)$ from $\Bbb R^2$), the vertical axis as the imaginary axis like $(0,1)$.

Comment: Some authors **define** complex numbers to be vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ that you can multiply with multiplication given by: $$(a,b)(c,d) = (ac - bd, ad+bc).$$ Traditionally, you associate $a+ib$ with the vector $(a,b)$. So really, $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb C$ are no different in my eyes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why is it that this way of translating vectors to the complex plane never produces contradictions? Why is that what the complex equation tells you is the "radial velocity" or the "tangential velocity" is actually that? How do you demonstrate such a thing? Namely, that as you derivate you'll always get the actual radial and tangential components of whatever (acceleration or velocity), even if you're just mingling around with complex numbers?

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments